# БД из SQL в Mysql

Tags: c#, sql-server, mysql

поясните такой момент, а то представление не очень пока...

есть БД на SQL Server и прога для нее на C#. Как мне это выложить на хостинг?

Надо сделать эту БД на mysql уже непосредственно на хостинге?

Comment: как это связано с `php` в ваших тегах?

Comment: честно не знаю пока

Comment: И опишите, пожалуйста, поконкретнее, что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: в итоге, хочу чтобы моя прога, которая вытаскивает все таблица, фильтрует в них данные и т.д. оказалась на хостинге...

Comment: Прогу придется допиливать скорее всего, чтобы работала с mysql

Answer (score 2):

на хостинге стоит сервер MySQl.
тогда вам нада сделать дамп базы с вашего SQL Server а затем залить базу на хостинг- обычно  хостеры предоставляют phpMyAdmin - инструмент для администирования базы MySQL

Comment: только вот не на всех хостингах к базе дадут обратиться извне.

Comment: ну вот как-то так я себе и представляю это...видел там такое

Comment: to Nofate - phpMyAdmin стоит на сервере - поэтому это не есть доступ извне